# Is it possible to aggregate each BigQuery column by some expresion like SUM(*)

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a BQ table that contains 1 String column and many (>2000) Int columns. I want to write a simple query where I would be able to aggregate all records by the first string column and sum other integer columns. Something like that:

```
SELECT
  string_col,
  SUM(* EXCEPT(string_col))
FROM
  project_id.dataset_id.table_id
GROUP BY
  string_col
```

Is there any way to do smth like this? The goal is to avoid a declaration of all Int columns in the query, e.g. `SUM(int1_col), SUM(int2_col), ... , SUM(int2000_col)`

Comment: I don't think this is possible.  However, 2000 columns suggests a problem with your data model.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, agree regarding the data model but it's one of the sources which I cannot change

Comment: You might not be able to change that table but you could always take the data it holds, transform it into a more useable format and write it to other tables